# flutter: How I can pass gesture to children from GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, uigesturerecognizer, gesturedetector

I have the `GestureDetector`, and I detect only `onHorizontalDrag` if it started near the edges. How I can pass the gesture to `InteractiveViewer` if the gesture is not valid for me? `if(isHorizontalDragActive == false)`

```dart
            return GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
              onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
                // allows start only near L/R edges.
                final double dX = details.localPosition.dx;
                final double dW = constraints.maxWidth / 6;
                if (dX < dW || dX > (constraints.maxWidth - dW)) {
                  isHorizontalDragActive = true;
                } else {
                  isHorizontalDragActive = false;
                }
              },
              onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
                if (isHorizontalDragActive == true) {
                  final double velocity = details.primaryVelocity ?? 0;
                  if (velocity < 0) {
                    manager.toForwardPage();
                  } else if (velocity > 0) {
                    manager.toBackwardPage();
                  }
                }
                isHorizontalDragActive = false;
              },
              child: InteractiveViewer
```

Now if I scale `InteractiveViewer` I can't start moving content inside `InteractiveViewer` in a horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0):

A GestureDetector wrapping the InteractiveViewer will not respond to GestureDetector events as expected. Try listeners

```
  Listener(
    onPointerMove: (moveEvent){
       if(moveEvent.delta.dx > 0) {
           print("user swiped right");
       }
      }
      child: InteractiveViewer()
     .....
   )
```